# Tab filename naming and suffix

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rename sheets when being imported. So every pair of imported sheet is named Filename + Suffix (suffix should be different for sheet one and sheet two but the same every time a new workbook is being imported

e.g Test is being imported the sheet1 = test - report, sheet two = test - Pr

next time a file is imported e.g test1, then sheet1 = test1 - report, sheet two = test1 - Pr

A lot of information hope somebody can help.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FileNames As Variant
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim WSNew1 As Worksheet
    Dim WSNew2 As Worksheet
    Dim ActiveListWB As Workbook



    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
                                               Title:="Select Active List to Import", _
                                               MultiSelect:=True)
    If VarType(FileNames) = vbBoolean Then
        If Not FileNames Then Exit Sub
    End If


    For Each FileName In FileNames


        Set WSNew1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Set WSNew2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add


        Set ActiveListWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        ActiveListWB.Sheets("Resources").UsedRange.Copy WSNew1.Range("A1")
        ActiveListWB.Sheets("SC_Hours_Employee").UsedRange.Copy WSNew2.Range("A1")


        ActiveListWB.Close False
    Next FileName
End Sub
```

How do i name imported sheetnames with the filename from the imported workbook and sequentially add suffix Report and SHE for the two sheets in that order?

Comment: How do i name imported sheetnames with the filename from the imported workbook and sequentially add suffix

Report
and 
SHE 

for the two sheets in that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add in

```
WSNew1.name = ActiveListWB.name & " - report"
WSNew2.name = ActiveListWB.name & " - Pr"
```

before ActiveListWB.close, if I'm reading your question correctly